# Can i use content of $_SESSION[' '] to open a file?

Tags: php

in this case file  successfully  open

```
                $friend_id=$_POST['cc'];
                $extension='txt';
                $file_name="$friend_id.$extension";
                $handle1=fopen($file_name,'a');
```

Is there any way to open a file like this? codes are below

In this case unsuccessful to open file

```
 $user=$_SESSION['$username'];
 $extension='txt';
 $inbox_file_name="$user.$extension";
 $fh1=fopen($inbox_file_name,'a');
```

Comment: check if the file exists!! by the way: is there any error you are getting?

Comment: Be careful with '$username' and "$username"

Comment: @Saurabh Sinha its giving Warning: fopen(abc .txt): failed to open stream:

Comment: @abhi_123 thats why you should check first if the file exist. maybe create it if not.

Comment: Looks like you got a space in your filename? Or is that just a typo? (_Warning: fopen(abc .txt)_)

Answer (score 0):

This code might be helpful ie, avoid `'` in `$username`

```
$user=$_SESSION[$username];
$user = trim($user);
 $extension='txt';
 $inbox_file_name=$user.".".$extension;
 if(file_exists($inbox_file_name))
    $fh1=fopen($inbox_file_name,'a');
 else
     echo "file not exists";
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did here?

Comment: in this code you can not store $_SESSION[$username] in $user variable

Comment: Warning: fopen(USER::abhi_123 .txt): failed to open stream @Dhinju

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be:

```
$user=$_SESSION['$username'];
$ext ='.txt';

$file = $user.$ext;

$handle=fopen($file,'a');
```

Comment: How is this a *better* way than doing `$file.'.'.$ext` when `$ext = 'txt';`?

Comment: It eliminates the possible error of " Be careful with '$username' and "$username" –  Drakes 5 mins ago", and yes $file . '.'. $ext is correct if u want only store 'txt' in your variable.

Answer (score 0):

this one works perfectly

```
 $user=$_SESSION['$username'];
$user = trim($user);
$extension='txt';
$inbox_file_name=$user.".".$extension;
if(file_exists($inbox_file_name))
$fh1=fopen($inbox_file_name,'a');
 else
 echo "file not exists";
```